# More spaces concatenated between two values in array in php

Tags: php

There is only one space concatenated between them. How can we give more spaces between these two entities?

```html
$array[] = $row['model'] . " " . $row['quantity'];

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: You simply want more space within the string?

Comment: use "&nbsp;" in place of " ".

Comment: No one is working. &nbsp; remains same in typaheads when i search "model". Output is like this .... "  OR-5544 GD&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1  " and more spaces in double quote considered a single space

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below to add multiple spaces.

```
$array[] = $row['model'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['quantity'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&nbsp;` to add multiple spaces between strings:

```
$array[] = $row['model'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['quantity'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_repeat` function.

```
$array[] = $row['model'] .str_repeat("&nbsp;",10). $row['quantity'];
```